# QTP-match web edit value to web element using variable

Tags: qtp

```
set a = Description.Create
a("micclass").value="WebElement"
a("class").value="sbqs_c"
a("html tag").value="DIV"

set b = browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").ChildObjects(a)
msgbox b.count
'For i = 0 To b.count-1 Step 1
'print b(i).getroproperty("text")
'Next
For i = 0 To b.count-1 Step 1
    If b(i).getroproperty("text")="sagar movie" Then
        wait(2)
        browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=.*").webelement("class:=sbqs_c","html tag:=DIV","index:=" & i).Click
    End If
Next
```

above is the code where i am checking web edit value against hard coded value "sagar movie". But, now I want to check web edit value which is stored in a variable. This value comes from an Excel Sheet and stored in variable. Most important, I am unable to target web element, because there is no 'class' attribute for web element in my application.
Moreover, I am getting 'General Run Error', when I am trying to replace "sagar movie" with my variable.

Please help

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where is the "WebEdit" you keep referring to? Moreover, the line where you are clicking on the webelement can be replaced by b.item(i).Click

Comment: I just want to compare and click web element which matches my variable value

Comment: Could you be more clear for anyone to help you out. Do you want to retrieve value of web element and webedit and compare it with each other ?